# how can I change the background color of all posts on my server?

Tags: customization, themes, css

The default for the theme I'm using is to have a white background for any post (the part with the text, not the background that forms the border around it) on my wordpress installation. Is there a way I can set the the background for all pages in one shot.

I've tried adding the following css:

```
p
{
    background: #91C3C1;
}
```

but it only changes the background color for the paragraphs.

What element should I be changing? (in this case I'm using the "Responsive" theme from CyberChimps)

Comment: It depends on the container for the post. What is the rendered markup? Add that code to your question please.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to find the id/container type? What am I looking for in the source?

Comment: In the rendered output, right click on the post content, choose _inspect element_ from context menu, and look at the DOM in the debugger. You can go up in the element tree here until you find the post container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to add the following

```
.grid
{
    background: #91C3C1;
}

.page
{
    background: #91C3C1;
}
```

although, the border around the posts are still the default color; but I'll start a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background colour to the class ".post", that's the standard class for posts

```
.post { background: #91C3C1 !important;
```